# Не подключается фрагмент, что делать?

Tags: android

На 17 строке выбивает ошибку когда пытаюсь указать id контейнера для фрагмента(как мне кажется).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

error: no suitable method found for add(int,FragmentOne)
method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Fragment)
method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; FragmentOne cannot be converted to Fragment)

Сам фрагмент создан студией как создать бланк фрагмент.

fragment_one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FragmentOne">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

FragmentOne

```
package com.mysite.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentOne#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public FragmentOne() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentOne.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FragmentOne newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.root_layout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `FragmentManager` и `FragmentTransaction` из пакета `android.app...`, а `FragmentOne` из `android.support.v4.app...`.

Решение - поменять импорты `FragmentManager` и `FragmentTransaction`на `support`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

`getFragmentManager()` меняем на `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Можно конечно наоборот, импорт фрагмента заменить на пакет `android.app...`, но оно вроде как @Deprecated

Comment: @S.Oleg поправил импорты

Comment: Incompatible types.
Required:
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Found:
android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: Во FragmentOne import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: @S.Oleg какие импорты сейчас в MainActivity ?

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

Comment: getFragmentManager() возвращает android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: @S.Oleg замените его на `getSupportFragmentManager()`